# Is calling bundle constructors in multiple places expensive in terms of performance?

Tags: ios, swift, performance, bundle

I need to use the bundleWithPath: in different parts of the application at least 1000 times.

```
func someMethod() -> String {
    let path = Bundle(for: SomeClass.self).path(forResource: "someResource"),
    let bundle = Bundle(path: path)
    return bundle.someMethodReturningString
}
```

Is Bundle(path expensive in terms of performance?
Do I need to keep a reference to avoid multiple instances?

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation, the answer is no

These constructors initializes and returns a new instance only if there is no existing bundle associated with fullPath, otherwise it deallocates self and returns the existing object.

**[Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle)**

```
init(for: AnyClass)
Returns the NSBundle object with which the specified class is associated.

init?(identifier: String)
Returns the NSBundle instance that has the specified bundle identifier.

init?(url: URL)
Returns an NSBundle object initialized to correspond to the specified file URL.

init?(path: String)
Returns an NSBundle object initialized to correspond to the specified directory.
```

**[Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundle?language=objc)**

```
+ bundleWithURL:
Returns an NSBundle object that corresponds to the specified file URL.

+ bundleWithPath:
Returns an NSBundle object that corresponds to the specified directory.

+ bundleForClass:
Returns the NSBundle object with which the specified class is associated.

+ bundleWithIdentifier:
Returns the NSBundle instance that has the specified bundle identifier.

- initWithURL:
Returns an NSBundle object initialized to correspond to the specified file URL.
```